# Custom Credentials in Apache Zeppelin

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I need to store my custom credentials, which are specific to my library which runs on Spark Interpreter.

These credentials are available in JWT token and I can extend ActiveDirectoryGroupRealm of Shiro to extract this data. My question is as follows:

Can I store  this data in Credentials? (e.g. I put that in the spark interpreter group ..)

How do I access this from Credentials through API?

Thanks